# SSPI error on windows authenticated remote access only

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to figure out what is wrong with our server. Right now i have many accounts that are sql accounts and windows authenticated (domain accounts).

When i connect with ANY windows authenticated account i get an error

> Cannot generate SSPI context

The account is good. I have also been trying to connect simply using Management Studio and i get the same error. If i use any SQL accounts it works and all windows authenticated account fails.

That being said, if i do a remote desktop to the SQL server itself and try using Management Studio on the server itself, all Windows authenticated account works without error.

The error only shows for remote computer (same domain / ip range) when using windows authenticated connections.

i have found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811889/how-to-troubleshoot-the-cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message) but it doesn't fix anything. According to the doc no accounts should work if we are getting this error.

Now what changed, the only thing that change is that the server was a virtual machine on VMWare, there was a conversion done to switch it to hypervisor and the instance has been restarted.

Anyone else would know when SSPI error can show based of where the authentication request was called ? i haven't been able to find anything. Could possibly be a bad error. Our servers have been down for the whole weekend we still haven't found anyone with the same issue.

Important notes :
- PC that remote and connect to `SQL` are in the same domain, same physical location, plugged in the same rack mount network wise.
- Running using IP or DNS doesn't change anything.
- no error logs show up in `SQL` and neither in `Event Viewer` on the server

Comment: What does the SQL Server log show for the failed logins?

Comment: And have you tried connecting with the IP Address? Fully-Qualified Domain Name?  And is the Server's hostname in DNS the same as its computer name?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft IP, and DNS none works. still the same error. I have zero errors regarding logins showing on either SQL logs or windows event viewer. the error only show client side. Also running Kerberos config manager creates an empty log file.

Comment: Does the SQL Server error log show *anything* related to Kerberos or SSPI ?

Comment: @MaxVernon The ONLY logs i have in SQL are transactional backup every 15 minutes. Literally nothing else. Actually as far as i can go back i have only that until the log about the last reboot of the server about 2 hours ago.

Comment: `I have also been trying to connect simply using Management Studio and i get the same error.`--If you run this code using your account what is the output? `SELECT auth_scheme FROM sys.dm_exec_connections WHERE session_id = @@spid`

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Locally on the server (only way i can use windows authenticated) i get `NTLM` using any SQL account locally or remotely return `SQL`

Comment: I suggest you dump out your spn list and check if you have the proper ones, otherwise add those. To dump out `Setspn –L domain\serviceaccount >>c:\SPNLIST.txt`. To add `SETSPN -s MSSQLSVC/servername.domainName.tld:1433 domain\serviceAccount

SETSPN -s MSSQLSVC/servername.domainName.tld domain\serviceAccount
` . You need both. This is an example for default instance.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide Both are already there. We tried to add it anyways and we got a valid error saying it would be duplicate so it didn't execute the command.

Comment: Are you part of a DNS Group in the login list of the SQL Server? I might be wrong, but I think that i have had SSPI issues when the hosting company was doing something wrong with their DNS Server, resulting in SQL Server not being able to see who is part of the group.

Comment: @RandiVertongen i am not sure what you mean by DNS group but if you mean same DNS server we only have one that delivers all the names of each computer. Plus each IP are fix on each computers.

Comment: Oh my bad, I meant AD Group.

Comment: @RandiVertongen Yes they are. We only have 1 domain controller. We also tried playing with groups and users and putting a couple users `DomainAdmin` but nothing changes.

Comment: Hm, but it would probably show up in the logs if that was the case, but have you tried connecting with  a login not in a group?

Comment: @RandiVertongen Create a local user on the server. Putted him as part of administrator group. Added that login to SQL so it's valid. I can connect perfectly locally. Remotely i have no clue how i can connect with it.

Comment: I mean, just your regular AD Windows login, that has a corresponding Login on the sql server, so SQL Server knows which AD login it is, without having to look it up in the group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found how to fix the issue. Unfortunately we do not know why it fixes it as the old VMWare image have the same setting it has on the Hyper-V image. Both suddenly stopped working.

To fix it we had to change the SQL server instance that has been running on the main Domain admin account for the last 10 years to run on `LocalSystem` and both `SPN` were registered under a user account. That user was another domain admin account which was the one originally used when SQL was first installed 10 years ago. That account is still active and used. We removed the SPN from the account and put them directly under the SQL dns.

Note that i don't know that interface where SPN are listed but i understood that it list all computer DNS names and all user account of the domain and SPN can be under either. Both IT have no idea why this suddenly stopped working. According to oldest image backup of the servers those settings never changed but that's all we needed to do to make everything work again.